# Statistics Collector Policy-Not able to add custom dimensions

Tags: apigee

I am unable to add Custom Dimensions in Custom Reports using statistics collector and extract variable policy mentioned below.

I have followed all the steps given in tutorial and docs but still I am stuck.

**EXTRACT VARIABLE POLICY**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <ExtractVariables async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Extract-   Variables-1">
 <DisplayName>Extract Variables 1</DisplayName>
 <FaultRules/>
 <Properties/>
 <Source clearPayload="false">response</Source>
 <VariablePrefix></VariablePrefix>
 <XMLPayload stopPayloadProcessing="false">
    <Namespaces>
     <Namespace prefix="yweather">http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0</Namespace>
   </Namespaces>
    <Variable name="weather.location" type="string">
        <XPath>/rss/channel/link</XPath>
    </Variable>
    <Variable name="weather.condition" type="string">
        <XPath>/rss/channel/item/yweather:condition/@text</XPath>
    </Variable>
  <Variable name="weather.forecast_today" type="string">
        <XPath>/rss/channel/item/yweather:forecast[1]/@text</XPath>
    </Variable>
    <Variable name="weather.forecast_tommorow" type="string">
        <XPath>/rss/channel/item/yweather:forecast[2]/@text</XPath>
    </Variable>
</XMLPayload>
</ExtractVariables>
```

**STATISTICS COLLECTOR POLICY**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StatisticsCollector async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Statistics-Collector-1">
<DisplayName>Statistics Collector 1</DisplayName>
<FaultRules/>
 <Properties/>
<Statistics>
    <Statistic name="location" ref="weather.location" type="string">Earth</Statistic>
    <Statistic name="condition" ref="weather.condition" type="string">Sunny</Statistic>
    <Statistic name="forecast_today" ref="weather.forecast_today" type="string">Rainy</Statistic>
    <Statistic name="forecast_tomorrow" ref="weather.forecast_tomorrow" type="string">Balmy</Statistic>
</Statistics>
</StatisticsCollector>
```

Comment: Can you enable debug in Apigee Edge and then send a request through your proxy? When you see the request is captured in the debug view please download the file and attach it here. The debug file helps in understanding if the statistic variables are loaded with any values.

Comment: Could you let us know the nature of the issue you are facing i.e.are you not seeing the custom dimensions mentioned in the statscollector policy when you create a custom report or you are getting an error when you are running the statscollector policy. Please also let us know your org name.

Answer (score 0):

Your policies look fine (i.e., it looks like you haven't modified the samples in http://apigee.com/docs/analytics-services/content/analyze-api-message-content-using-custom-analytics), so the problem likely lies in your policy attachment, or, more likely, your deployment. Make sure your proxy is deployed in the expected environment. It can be useful to use the API to do this:
curl -u email:password https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org_name}/apis/{api_name}/deployments

If your API proxy is deployed properly, please post your ProxyEndpoint configuration, and the request that you are sending to the API proxy and we'll take it from there.